# how to use NSIS to build an installer that can install modules to specific path

Tags: windows-installer, nsis

I'm a newbee to windows. We have code which is managed by github. I want to use NSIS script(no UI) to create a windows installer. The installer should do:

- copy the files in github to specific windows folder. e.g. C:\TargetFolder

What's the steps should I do? can the NSIS script automatically compress the github files during create a installer? and I can copy these to specific windows folders?

Expectation:

- can have a nsis script example about how to automatically compress github code in nsis script.
- can have a nsis script example about how to copy github files to specific windows folder with installer

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. Learn the basics of NSIS from its documentation. If you have a _specific problem_, with existing code, you're invited to ask the StackOverflow community for help.

Comment: What are github files? Are you talking about downloading from a repository during install?